# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when using a SoapClient

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in node.js, and I am experimenting things recently. A few days ago, I have tried to send a XML request to an API, with the use of easysoap-request. It worked perfectly, but I would have had to create an XML file for each different query, so I tried with easysoap. I found myself stuck pretty quickly, but I managed to resolve some issues with the help of this website. Now my program give an error that I have trouble understanding. Here my code first:

```html
const EasySoap = require('easysoap');
const request = (async () => {

    const params = {
        host    : 'https://someapi.com',
        path    : '/dir/soap',
        wsdl    : '/dir/wsdl',
        headers: [{
            'user-agent': 'Request-Promise',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        }]
    }

    var soapClient = EasySoap(params);

    soapClient.call({
        method    :'one_methode',
        attributes: {
            xmlns: 'https://someapi.com'
        },
        params: {
            'api' : {
                'authentication' : {
                    'login' : 'mylogin',
                    'password' : 'mypassword'
                },
                'params' : {
                    'another_params' : {
                        'name' : 'Brian',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).then((callResponse) => {
        console.log(callResponse.data); // response data as json
        console.log(callResponse.body); // response body
        console.log(callResponse.header);  //response header
    }).catch((err) => { 
        throw new Error(err);
    });
});
request();
```

And the error it give me:

node:10264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: no wsdl/xml response at soapClient.call.then.catch (C:\Users\user\Documents\src\script.js:40:15) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:10264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:10264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Is this a problem with the .catch() ? Can someone explain me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're throwing error inside `catch`, which is wrapped to `Promise.reject` since it's thrown inside `async` function, and not `catching` anywhere.

```
...
}).catch((err) => { 
  throw new Error(err);
});
```

You can either handle the error in that block like `console.error(err)`
or handle in your `request()` function call like

```
// request returns promise since you wrapped it in async function
request()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```